# Wrong syntax highlighting with command substitution in sh-mode [bash]

Tags: syntax-highlighting, shell-mode

I am using the Doom framework (3.0.0) for Emacs (28.1) on Windows 10 with MinGW64. At least for all practical purposes to the effect of my work, everything seems to be running smoothly except for the wrong syntax highlighting of command substitution in shell-mode, as you can see in the image attached below.

[image: Line with wring highlighting]

The defect is in the substring `'s/^\([A-Z]\+\` of the sed command, which should be highlighted precisely as the remaining substring up to the closing single quotation mark. This is not a theme-dependent effect.

Any help to preserve inside the scope of command substitution the general highlighting style will be appreciated.